# How to get the screen on which the windows is maximized on?

Tags: winforms

In Windows Forms, how can I get the screen on which a Window was maximized on? I have a lot of problems finding that screen when I maximize a Form on my right screen.

Currently I have been iterating over all the screens with a IntersectsWith check. But if your windows is positioned on both the screens before maximizing, both screens will intersect with the RestoreBounds of the window. As a result I will still not know on which screen the window was maximized on...

If I use the DesktopBounds, then they both screens also intersect with them. This is very strange as those bounds are really bounds of a maximized Form on my right screen (1912, 87, 1456, 916). How is it possible that my left screen intersects with those bounds?

Apparently my left screen has a resolution of 1920x1080, so the question really is why the DesktopBound.Left value is 1912 when maximized on my right screen? Shouldn't it be 1921?

Code snippet:

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var screen in Screen.AllScreens)
    {
        if (screen.Bounds.IntersectsWith(this.DesktopBounds))
        {
            //Found screen
        }
    }
}
```

to get the whole picture, we save the bounds and windowstate of the Form when it is closed. When it is opened again, it is restored to the same bounds and windowstate.

Comment: Use `screen.WorkingArea` instead of `screen.Bounds`. `DesktopBounds` is based on the working area, not on the screen area. Also, see answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use `Screen.FromControl(this)` to get the screen where the form is positioned... however you should check if it's maximized beforehand, else that'll get you the screen where the largest part of the form is (then again, that'd be the screen where the form would maximize to in case you maximized it).